# I am trying to understand the concept of passing my reference (pointers) in a Singly Linked List implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to implement a singly linked list in JavaScript and I am having a hard time visualizing the concept of passing my reference (and what is pointing where). My code is below and I have followed it up with a few questions or my understanding, can you please go over it and let me know if I am thinking in the right direction.

```
class Node{
    constructor(val){
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedLists {
    constructor(){
        this.head = null;
        this.length = 0;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    // methods
    addNodeStart(val){
        let node = new Node(val);
        if (this.length === 0){
            this.length++;
            this.head = node;
            this.tail = node;

        } else {
            node.next = this.head;
            this.head = node;
            this.length++;
        }
        return this;
    }

    addNodeEnd(val){
        let node = new Node(val);

        if (this.length === 0){
            this.length++;
            this.head = node;
            this.tail = node;

        } else {
            this.length++;
            this.tail.next = node;
            this.tail = node;
        }
    }
}
```

My Understandings:

1. In adding a node to the start (addNodeStart) first we create a new Node with the given val and put the if statement to check if the length is 0 and then set the tail and head both to the new node.
2. Else If the length > 1, then first point the `node.next` to `this.head` (this.head is pointing to a Node which was set as the head). So is `this.head` just a container holding the reference to a node?? or is this.head an actual node? Then again set this.head to node. So is this.head just a variable name, for example let x = 5; here x references to the memory location of 5.

So is my thinking of this.head being just a container (variable) that holds the value of a node? or am I missing the something here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish. But maybe this is helpful debugging your list: https://jsfiddle.net/nh0cLpq7/1/

you can use an toArray method and then inspect your list in the console.

```
LinkedLists.prototype.toArray = function() {
  let = element = this.head
  const array = []
  while(element) {
    array.push(element)
    element = element.next || null
  }
  return array
}
```

[image]